# I want to run a bunch of terminal commands consecutively, and repeatedly, on a raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, raspberry-pi4, inky

I have a raspberry pi 4 with a inkyWHAT display, I've managed to get the display showing my own images.

What I need help with is to run the following commands one after the other, at present I paste each line in one at a time:

```
from PIL import Image
from inky import InkyWHAT
inky_display = InkyWHAT("yellow")
inky_display.set_border(inky_display.YELLOW)
img = Image.open("/home/pi/Desktop/test2.jpg")
w, h = img.size
h_new = 300
w_new = int((float(w) / h) * h_new)
w_cropped = 400
img = img.resize((w_new, h_new), resample=Image.LANCZOS)
x0 = (w_new - w_cropped) / 2
x1 = x0 + w_cropped
y0 = 0
y1 = h_new
img = img.crop((x0, y0, x1, y1))
pal_img = Image.new("P", (1, 1))
pal_img.putpalette((255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0) + (0, 0, 0) * 252)
img = img.convert("RGB").quantize(palette=pal_img)
inky_display.set_image(img)
inky_display.show()
```

Not only that, but I'd like to run this every 15 minutes, or so. With no interaction from me at all.

I appreciate this may be really basic for some but this will be my very first time venturing into this kind of thing.

Comment: Use `crontab` to make something run every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save the file as myfile.py then in a terminal issue

```
chmod +x myfile.py  # to make file executable ( only need to do this once )

python myfile.py  #  execute the code
```

By the looks of it it wants to create an output window ... if its output is not visual namely is some output file then you can put into a cronjob to run at some frequency ... issue  `crontab -l` to display local cronjobs on a given machine for current user ... get into edit mode to edit cronjobs by issuing  `crontab -e`  ... here is a one liner to run something every 15 minutes

```
0,15,30,45 * * * *  /usr/bin/python /some/dir/myfile.py
```

cronjob is created per user and it does not source your ~/.bashrc so if it needs jacked up env vars then those must be made visible to a given cronjob sometime its handy to create a wrapper bash shell script to do those preliminary and post processing steps YMMV